# Create my own UI for nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to create my own UI for NuGet, for example in my MVC project I would like to download and install a NuGet package from the admin section in my web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, we do this with ASP.NET WebPages built in admin :)

A good starting point would be to look at the NuGet Commandline's install command to see how it does it.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e2929b936dfb#src%2fCommandLine%2fCommands%2fInstallCommand.cs